# canvas position getting move after adding to fabric

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

I have created canvas on my screen. When I wrap it for Fabric.js with below line it is getting moved from position. Please suggest what would be the reason.

**HTML::**

```
<canvas id="design_text"   style="border:1px solid #000000; ">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
```

**CSS::**

```
#middle_panel {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top:15px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    height: 500px;
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 27%;
}
```

**JS ::**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design_text');
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your whole code? Are you ahving an CSS defined on design_text?

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi yes css are defined , but just width and height

Comment: can u please post your code..

Comment: can you atleast provide CSS of that div and its parent's???

Comment: @CodeJack have added parent div's css , and on canvas css is applied only for width and height .

Comment: anyways this is also not helping..I am assuming left panel and right panel are in middle_panel...plz check if canvas position is set to absolute??

Comment: @CodeJack now left panel and right are not inside middle panel ,should i set can position to absolute ? is it required?

Comment: ok middle_panel is the central part that excludes right and left panel and u r using margin-left:27% to avoid left panel collision..if am right..I feel you should have same parent for right, left and middle panels and use float:right to the right one and float:left to the remaining two...